# Replace file names using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, file, file-rename

I want to rename a lot of files using SQL. Is this possible?

I want to change:

> \[servername]\[Location][Filename]_20180816.xls

to:

> \[servername]\[Location][NewFilename]_20180816.xls

All the files have the same name *but the suffix is different dates* (i.e: 20180816) which I want to keep.

Comment: use regular expressions

Comment: I think powershell would probably be a far better suited tool for this.

Comment: Why do you think this is a task well-suited to a database engine?

Comment: Are you trying to rename the actual files or are you trying to update your database which stores the file name?

Comment: Also, where is the value of `[NewFilename]` coming from?

Comment: Might be SSIS (script task or file system task) could be a fit as well for these kind of tasks.

Comment: @SeanLange I am trying to rename the actual file name.

Comment: @Larnu thanks for the advice, but I'm limited. This is work related and there is limited access to resources (SQL Server is what I am limited to.) The files are generated from another program, which was coded by another individual, which I have since changed/fixed.

Comment: The only way SQL Server (using T-SQL) could rename the files would be via `xp_cmdshell`, however, if you're using that, then you have access to tools such as PowerShell. I'd suggest if you're being told you're limited to only using SQL Server you're being limited to not being able to actually do what you've been asked. Quite simply, what you're asking for can't be done with SQL Server alone (and even then, SQL Server is still the wrong choice). Effectively you've been asked to push a cube through a circle shaped hole of the same size; unsurprisingly the cube does not fit.

Comment: @Larnu you could put that as an answer and Ill give you some points =) I wasnt asked to do it using SQL Server. I was just wondering because I don't want to rename over 500 files manually

Comment: @OngaLeo-YodaVellem it doesn't actually solve your problem though. I'm not worried about the point, if you think the comment is relevant, just upvote that. :) If you can expand on your requirements/exposure to tools then I'll be happy to try and provide an actual solution to your problem.

Comment: Then why *can't* you using Powershell, or similar, instead? Powershell is a great tool for tasks such as this.

Comment: Renaming actual files and using t-sql is completely the wrong tool. It is so far away from the right tool for the job I don't even know where to begin. This should be done in a programming language, not a database.